# Monitoring a Windows JBOSS installation with Nagios

Tags: windows, jboss, monitoring, jmx, nagios

I'm using the jboss2nagios plugin for Linux severs but what about Windows servers?

Is there a solution to monitor the memory usage and number of threads?
I'm using NSClient++ as the agent

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know jboss2nagios works exactly the same on windows and linux. Your nagios node connects to the collector mbean installed into your jboss to recollect metrics.

You don't need nsclient since it is the mbean collector which open the port 5566 (by default) and allows nagios to connect to.

Comment: But I need NsClient++ to check other stuff on my server, and it is listening on 5666. If I close it and put the collector.sar into my jboss installation I see no port 5666 listening

Comment: You need both services. NsClient to check the SO status and collector.sar to check the jboss. You must use different ports.